# When using ASP.NET core Identity, it is better to extend the User class or write separate entities that relate to it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to use the Identity system provided by ASP.NET core. Most tutorials I read extend the User class by adding custom properties like the following:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    // etc...
}
```

This seems fine when you only have few properties. But what if I want to add a long list of other properties, like their full address, their memberships, etc.

From a design perspective, is it better (and even possible) to write separate entities that store these custom properties and in the ApplicationUse class add navigation properties that can be used to access these entities, like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
    // Other navigation properties
}
```

How do most professional developers approach this? I am new to programming and learning it in my spare time to land a job in software development.

Comment: You could make use of [partial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) classes. Wherever using partial overall and if it is a better approach or not, is a whole different topic.

Comment: @Twenty That's really my question, whether it is better to simply add columns to the User table or write separate tables that I navigate to. I'm thinking if I show this to a potential employer, they might ask me about my design choices. I want to get this right

Comment: You extends IdentityUser to add more columns to the user table, the question whether to split these attributes or not its a SQL design question and its not related to ASP.NET core. Anyway I suggest not to split until the table become very big or the data could be referenced by other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about if the properties will need to exist apart from the `ApplicationUser`.

For example, it's unlikely that the `Address` will exist on its own and have its own key. In other words, you probably won't need an `Address` record to be shared between multiple `ApplicationUser` records. This means you probably won't need an `Addresses` table. For properties like this, consider using [Owned Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities).

However, it is likely that a `Membership` record will need to exist on its own and have its own key. It will probably be a join between an `ApplicationUser` record and another record (like a `Group`) with a payload (such as an `ExpirationDate` or a `Cost`). This means you will probably need a `Memberships` join table. For properties like this, consider using [many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many) relationships.